# Start Rhomobile app on NFC Tap

Tags: android, nfc, rhomobile

All,

Using only code is there any way to Start the App when perticular NFC has been tapped?

I have seen some Andriodmanifest.xml changes but not luck so far.

following changes i have done in manifest.

```
<intent-filter>  

<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>  

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 

<data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http" />

</intent-filter>
```

Where NFC Tag has example.com stored.

Thanks for the Help in advance.

Regards ,

Amit

Comment: What is the *exact* content that is stored in the NFC tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks NFC Guy. I figured out the way.
Here it is

```
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:path="" />  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```