# How can I pass the NFC badge data to Application when app is closed

Tags: android, nfc, rhomobile

I figured out the way to open the application by Tapping the phone on NFC Badge [Start Rhomobile app on NFC Tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835870/start-rhomobile-app-on-nfc-tap/12949279#12949279).

But the issue is how can I pass the NFC badge data to Application when app is closed?

Comment: An activity filter or an Android Application Record?

Comment: An Activity filter will only open the app, Need a way to pass the data from NFC badge to the App when its completely closed.

Comment: Completely closed? As in not visible?

Comment: Service [App > Running > Stop]is stopped . Its easy to pass the data to the App which is running in background.

Comment: So you need to pass the NFC data to some background service which is already running?

Comment: anything will do. need to pass data to application . if its a background service . Do you know how to create it in Rhomobile?